# c# Thread.Sleep() into Timer

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
int i = 5000;
Console.WriteLine("waiting" + i + "miliseconds");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(i);
i = 3000;
Console.WriteLine("waiting" +  i + "miliseconds");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(i);
Console.WriteLine("finish");
```

During the sleep my program doesn't respond. How can sleep be translated into the timer functions?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Msonic a simple console app looks more likely. OP, what response are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> During the sleep my programm doesnt respond

Well... yeah, that's what you're telling it to do.  You're suspending the main thread, so how could it possibly do anything other than wait?

If you want to launch a background thread or timer you will need to use one of those classes.  You do not explain what you are actually trying to accomplish here, so the best advice I can give is to go look up some example code for the `BackgroundWorker` or `Timer` classes (there are a few `Timer` classes, chose the one that best fits what you are trying to do).

Answer (score 1):

You will want to set up an actual `Timer` in that case. Please see the following [example of how to do this.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer) You cannot have your code sleep and move on at the same time. The closest you might have to something like that is if you want to use the C# 5.0 `async` functionality.

At bare minimum, it sounds like what you are indeed looking for is to write [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx). If you follow the links or perform your own google searches around these subjects, that should help you.